# MongoDB N:M relation

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to implement a kind of Access Control List for documents stored in MongoDB. I have users and items and the user have different rights on the items, e.g. read, write, delete... How do I store this n:m relation best in MongoDB?

I came up with the following ideas:

1. An ACL document : `{itemID:"1", userID:"2", right:"write"}`
2. An ACL per item : `{itemID:"1", users {"2" : "write", "3" : "read"}}`
3. Embedded ACL in the user : `{_id:"1",..., users {"2" : "write", "3" : "read"}}`
4. Embedded ACL in the item : `{_id:"1",..., users {"2" : "write", "3" : "read"}}`

Approaches 1 & 2 have clearly the disadvantage, that I have to query mongo twice and do the join form ACL to item by myself. The same holds true in most cases for solution 3, so to me approach 4. seems somehow the best, but I would be happy to hear some opinions on that!

Cheers,

Klaus

Comment: how about this, `{itemId:"1",..., access: {"read" : ["1","2"], "write": ["3"] }}`